# Getting a list of wireless network history?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

In Windows 7, I can go to `Control Panel` > `Network and Sharing Center` > `Manage Wireless Networks` to see and manage all of the Home and Work networks I've connected to.

However, I'd like to see a list of every wireless network I've ever connected to, private or public. I know Windows keeps track of it somehow because if I connect to a public network I've already set up, it doesn't ask me what type of connection it is.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst there may be third party software or logs you can set up, I am not aware of this behavior on a default/standard Windows installation.

When you connect to a wireless network, one of the stages (In Windows 7, it is just before you connect) is to `Save Automatically`. If you do this, it is saved to the list that you stated, if however you do not select this, after you disconnect there is no trace left on your machine.

As for the behaviour you experience, I am really not to sure. I will try to do some experiments when I have some free time and see if I can find out any additional information for you.